# In MSSQL filter rows based on an ID exists in a column as comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've Benchmarking table like this

```
BMID      TestID     BMTitle    ConnectedTestID
---------------------------------------------------
1          5         My BM1          0
2          6         My BM2          5
3          7         My BM3          5,6
4          8         My BM4          10,12,8
5          9         My BM5          0
6          10        My BM6          3,6
7          5         My BM7          8,3,12,9
8          3         My BM8          7,10
9          8         My BM9          0
10         12        My BM10         9
---------------------------------------------
```

Explaining the table a little

Here the TestID and the connected TestID is playing the roles. If the user wants all the benchmarks for the TestID 3

It should return rows where testID=3 and also if any rows having connectedTestID column having that testID in it among the comma separated values

That means if the user specify the value 3 as the testID, it should return

```
---------------------------------------------
8          3         My BM8          7,10
7          5         My BM7          8,3,12,9
6          10        My BM6          3,6
--------------------------------------------
```

Hope its clear how those 3 rows returned. Means First row is because the testID 3 is there. the other two rows because 3 is in their connectedIDs cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should fix the data structure.  Storing numeric ids in a comma-delimited list is a bad, bad, bad idea:

- SQL Server doesn't have the best string manipulation functions.
- Storing numberings as character strings is a bad idea.
- Having undeclared foreign key relationships is a bad idea.
- The resulting queries cannot make use of indexes.

While you are exploring what a junction table is so you can fix the problem with the data structure, you can use a query such as this:

```
where testid = 3 or
      ',' + ConnectedTestID + ',' like '%,3,%'
```

Comment: Unfortunately Ive been asked to not touch the structure of an existing table. Only permitted thing was to use a column which was not using for anything.. With that situation I thought about this was the only solution... Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: @sforsandeep . . . The point is that you should be using *another* table.  Storing the list would require no changes at all to this table (well, it would be helpful to have `TestId` be the primary key of some table so you can declare foreign key relationships).

Comment: Thats true sir.. But unfortunately Im not been permitted to create another table for the scenario. I presented a solution with another table exactly as you said. But I dont know my boss been said to use this table alone to provide that solution. Thus I came up with this idea..

Comment: @sforsandeep - then I'd strongly suggest to your boss that a log of accumulating technical debt is created.  Because decisions like these can often snow ball - in terms of maintainability, significant performance penalty, etc, etc.